# <br> not working properly using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, append

When I add `<br>` through DOM, it isn't working properly...
The `<br>` isn't doing its job. Everything else is working perfectly fine. *I think it is some problem with `.append()` method...*

[image: The Image of the output.]
[Here is the live demo](https://codepen.io/Darkzite/pen/GREBpyB) *(**Note:** The live demo is now fixed. But the below code is of the non-fixed)*
Here is the code:

JS:

```js
const urls = [
  {
    src:
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRtFPba2-cBeIyhZ3Sxlkd2fGZegsdcqEEoww&usqp=CAU",
    name: "John Doe",
    email: "foobar@example.com"
  }
];
urls.forEach((person) => {
  const profile = document.createElement("div");
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = person.src;
  const hr = document.createElement("hr");
  const name = document.createTextNode("Name: " + person.name);
  const br = document.createElement("br");
  const email = document.createTextNode("Email: " + person.email);
  profile.append(img, hr, name, br, email);
  document.body.append(profile, br);
});
```

CSS:

```css
div {
  border: 5px solid #ca6702;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2a9d8f;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  border: 4px solid #264653;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

hr {
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #e9d8a6;
}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) which also applies to any other external resource.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I can't see anything wrong with this question @tacoshy

Comment: @MorKadosh it does not contain a working [repro] in the question itself. The question requirs to use external resoruces or an IDE to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Jithin, you should make it a code snippet.

Comment: @tacoshy there is a `codepen` link, what am I missing?

Comment: @trinalbadger587 Hmmm.... How should I do it?

Comment: read the link. Or post a codepen in a question and you see a warnign stating that a codepen should not be used as repalcement of a [repro]. It is only allowed to be used as an extension (see the the links explainations).

Comment: @Jithin, use `Ctrl+M`

Comment: @trinalbadger587 I am on mobile...

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: @Andreas it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Don't pick single words from a whole paragraph. You should describe the behavior you're expecting and hat the actual behavior is. And if there's an error then what that error says (preferable copy&paste) ;)

Comment: Don't edit your question and add the solution to your problem. Accept the answer that fixed your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `document.createElement()` creates only 1 element and you can append it to the dom only once.  Creating a second one or cloning your `br` should fix your issue.

```
const urls = [
  {
    src:
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRtFPba2-cBeIyhZ3Sxlkd2fGZegsdcqEEoww&usqp=CAU",
    name: "John Doe",
    email: "foobar@example.com"
  }
];
urls.forEach((person) => {
  const profile = document.createElement("div");
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = person.src;
  const hr = document.createElement("hr");
  const name = document.createTextNode("Name: " + person.name);
  const br = document.createElement("br");
  const br2 = document.createElement("br");
  
  const email = document.createTextNode("Email: " + person.email);
  profile.append(img, hr, name, br, email);
  document.body.append(profile, br2);
});
```

Comment: Yes it solved the problem. I didn't knew about it... Thanks a lot!

Comment: A templating engine (or just a template literal when you can be sure that the content of `urls` won't ever contain anything user-controlled) would be a viable option.

Comment: From [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) but it's the same for `.append()`: _" The `Node.appendChild()` method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. **If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, `appendChild()` moves it from its current position to the new position** (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node). This means that **a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously**."_

Answer (score 0):

Every time you append a `<br>` element, you need to create it one more time to append it again. In your case it can look like this:

```
const br1 = document.createElement("br");
const email = document.createTextNode("Email: " + person.email);
profile.append(img, hr, name, br1, email);
const br2 = document.createElement("br");
document.body.append(profile, br2);
```